# FATAL ERROR: AzerothCore does not support MySQL versions below 5.6

Tags: mysql, azerothcore

I was using the emulator on Ubuntu 20.04 using Mysql 8.0.27 and out of nowhere it started giving an error when uploading `./authserver` and `./worldserver`, using the following error:

> /home/wow/azerothcore/src/common/Database/DatabaseWorkerPool .cpp:21 in DatabaseWorkerPool FATAL ERROR:
> AzerothCore does not support MySQL versions below 5.6
> Segmentation fault (core dumped).

I already reinstalled MYSQL, in several versions, and did not solve the problem.

[AzerothCore does not support MySQL versions below 5.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HCGZ.jpg)

I tried to install MYSQL, I installed versions 5.6, 5.7, 8.0 again, but no success

Comment: always make sure you are using the latest version of AC (or at least a recent one) and there is no need to use outdated MySQL versions too.

Answer (score 2):

Well we got two issues here.

First of all bug reports should go on GitHub

Second of all you are using a core that is at least 2 years old.

Updating your source to the latest version should solve your issues =)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Azerothcore does not support MySQL 5.6 or lower. Please migrate and build with MySQL 5.7 or higher.